# The application has stopped unexpectedly while running fragment and tablayout app

Tags: android

I am beginner in Android while running my APP which only contain the tabs and fragments. Help me out to fix this bug `The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. Error` 
I have three Fragment classes and respective xml files. I am using ApI9.

I got this code from the youtube tutorial. There is no error at compile time. 
I have already tried two different ways to fix the problem:

1. Cleaning the project.
2. Restarting.

**My MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.slidenerdtab;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("TAB 1");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("TAB 2");
        tab2.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab3 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab3.setText("TAB 3");
        tab3.setTabListener(this);
        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(tab3);

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")@Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        Log.d("hai", "ontabReselected at" + "position" + tab.getPosition() + "name" + tab.getText());

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)@Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.d("hai", "ontabReselected at" + "position" + tab.getPosition() + "name" + tab.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.d("hai", "ontabReselected at" + "position" + tab.getPosition() + "name" + tab.getText());

    }

}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.slidenerdtab"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.slidenerdtab.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.slidenerdtab.FragmentActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.slidenerdtab.FragmentB"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment_b" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.slidenerdtab.FragmentC"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment_c" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MY LOGCAT**

```
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.slidenerdtab/com.example.slidenerdtab.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.slidenerdtab.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.slidenerdtab-1.apk]
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.slidenerdtab.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.slidenerdtab-1.apk]
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
07-22 23:23:02.029: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  ... 11 more
07-22 23:23:02.050: W/ActivityManager(58):   Force finishing activity com.example.slidenerdtab/.MainActivity
07-22 23:23:02.560: W/ActivityManager(58): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{43e35c50 com.example.slidenerdtab/.MainActivity}
07-22 23:23:02.580: I/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: 25317 ms (total 25317 ms)
07-22 23:23:12.662: W/ActivityManager(58): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{43e35c50 com.example.slidenerdtab/.MainActivity}
07-22 23:23:12.700: D/KeyguardViewMediator(58): pokeWakelock(5000)
07-22 23:23:13.029: D/KeyguardViewMediator(58): pokeWakelock(5000)
07-22 23:23:13.429: W/WindowManager(58): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
07-22 23:23:13.839: I/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x31a9d8:0x31aa94] in 605217 ns
07-22 23:23:16.359: I/Process(276): Sending signal. PID: 276 SIG: 9
07-22 23:23:16.379: I/ActivityManager(58): Process com.example.slidenerdtab (pid 276) has died.
07-22 23:23:16.609: I/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x31b0d8:0x31b2a0] in 1528452 ns
07-22 23:27:50.799: D/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
07-22 23:32:50.842: D/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: Clean the project once and try running.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Project` properties. Select `android dependencies` and `android private libraries` on `java build path` category under `order and export` tab. Then clean the project once and run.